# React.component return method is confusing

Tags: components, reactjs

So I'm trying to learn React.js and I'm starting off by reading from Tutorials Point. I created the sample React app as per their instructions and it came out pretty well.

My question is, I saw this `React.component()` method declaration [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_jsx.htm) in the App.jsx file. They have returned actual HTML code inside a return method. I've never seen this kind of return statement before.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

It doesn't even return it as a string or an object (Correct me if I'm wrong here).

If someone could explain this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's actually `JSX` - an XML/tree-like structure that React uses to derive a "virtual" DOM," which helps for performance so the rendering engine doesn't have to re-render the entire UI with each change of state. There are a lot of articles on it. I'm not going to reiterate the [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform) in a comment, though.

Comment: You can see here what the html stuff turns into. Hint: JavaScript https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20x%20%3D%20%3Cdiv%20%2F%3E

Comment: This definitely helps. Thanks @MarkC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML looking syntax is not actually HTML and not all HTML properties will work in it. It is JSX, JSX is a preprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript. For example if you try to use **class** as a property in the .JSX file it will not actually apply your CSS class:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div class="cssClass">
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

You must do this. Notice **class** is now **className**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="cssClass">
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

You do not have to use the JSX syntax to write React applications but it makes it a little more readable. You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). ReactJS will grab this syntax and render it into HTML elements. Also here are some [gotchas](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html) that make it different from HTML.